# Showing balance in available stocks in inventory for every day

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following query doesn't show balance quantity where there is inwards balance and also I want data for every day:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
P.ResourceName as ItemName,
P.ResourceRate as Rate,
i.TotalInQty as InwardsQuantity,
s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
i.TotalInQty-S.TotalOutQty as Balance,
O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
 ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select COALESCE(sum(i.Qty), 0) AS TotalInQty, Nameofitem, Min(I.Date) AS Date
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select COALESCE(sum(s.qty), 0) AS TotalOutQty, Nameofitem, Min(S.Date) AS Date
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem
) S
ON I.Date=S.Date 
AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

Can any body give an insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date,
P.ResourceName as ItemName,
P.ResourceRate as Rate,
COALESCE(i.TotalInQty,0) as InwardsQuantity,
--s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
COALESCE(s.TotalOutQty,0) as OutwardsQuantity,
--i.TotalInQty-s.TotalOutQty as Balance,
COALESCE(i.TotalInQty,0)-COALESCE(S.TotalOutQty,0) as Balance,
O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit 
FROM UnitMaster O 
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P 
    ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode 
    LEFT JOIN(select sum(i.Qty) AS TotalInQty,Nameofitem,Min(I.Date) AS Date  from Inwards_Master I where Tendercode=1 group by Nameofitem) I ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName 
    LEFT JOIN(select sum(s.qty) AS TotalOutQty,Nameofitem, Min(S.Date) AS Date  from Outwards_Master S where Tendercode=1 group by s.Nameofitem) S ON I.Date=S.Date AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem 
WHERE P.Status=1 and P.TenderCode= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the first issue is that you're using `COALESCE` at the wrong level - what you actually want to do is eliminate a `NULL` that is produced because the `LEFT JOIN` is unsuccessful. You can't eliminate that `NULL` in the subquery because it doesn't exist in that rowset:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
P.ResourceName as ItemName,
P.ResourceRate as Rate,
COALESCE(i.TotalInQty,0) as InwardsQuantity,
COALESCE(s.TotalOutQty,0) as OutwardsQuantity,
COALESCE(i.TotalInQty,0)-COALESCE(S.TotalOutQty,0) as Balance,
O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
 ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(i.Qty) AS TotalInQty, Nameofitem, Min(I.Date) AS Date
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(s.qty) AS TotalOutQty, Nameofitem, Min(S.Date) AS Date
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem
) S
ON I.Date=S.Date 
AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

Comment: oh it worked very well, can u please tell me what should be done to view data for every day, actually i want to maintain data for every day for any future reference

Comment: @kunaljangade - not entirely sure what you're asking. If you're wanting to have per-day breakdowns, then you need to make `Date` part of the `GROUP BY` clause rather than be in an aggregate. If `Date` contains a time portion as well, you probably want to do `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,I.Date),0)` in both the `SELECT` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause. If it's something else you're asking (maybe to include days for which you have no transaction data), you might need to add a calendar table to your system.

Comment: yes u got me right on this, i want to see stocks for every day in a     group by date form. and yes i have time part in date. can you please guide me on that?

Comment: @kunaljangade - I already said in my previous comment how to remove time from a `datetime` column, and that you ought to perform that same operation in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses of your subqueries.

Comment: i tried out your changes but there is an error in execution. it will be so nice if you can edit your answer please